# Show a language is regular with Myhill-Nerode Theorem

Tags: computer-science, equivalence-relations, automata, regular-language

I understand how to show a language is not regular using [Myhill-Nerode Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) (proof by contradiction), but how do you show the language is regular?

Take language $0^*1^*$ for example. I know this language is regular (I can build a dfa), but how do I apply Myhill-Nerode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Myhill-Nerode Theorem says that a language $L$ is regular *if and only if* the number of equivalences classes of the relation $R_L$ is finite, where 
$$
x R_L y \iff x, y \text{ have no distinguishing extension.}
$$
(Terminology and notation are as in the article you cite.)
In the case of $0^*1^*$, it's not hard to show that the equivalence classes are:

- the equivalence class of $\varepsilon$, which equals the eq. class of $0$,
- the equivalence class of $1$, and
- the equivalence class of strings not in the language.

There are three, so the language is regular. The theorem also says that when $L$ is regular, the number of equivalence classes equals the minimum number of states of DFAs recognizing the language. Probably the DFA you figured out *is* that minimal DFA.